# LAMP Stack refresh rate is poor

Tags: apache-http-server, php, web, lamp

I'm using LAMP on Linux(Debian). Earlier I used WAMP on Windows. Whenever I saved the PHP file and tested on the browser, it immediately takes effect. However, in Linux, the LAMP takes too much time to refresh the PHP file, even though I manually refresh the browser site.
Is there any way to improve LAMP response time?

Lamp version: lampstack-8.0.12-0
OS: Linux Debian [Kali linux 2021.3]

Comment: Add to your post what **Linux distro and its version** you're running on your computer and  **LAMP version** too.

Comment: Is that PHP file just single file or one from several ones of a web system.

Comment: *"LAMP takes too much time to refresh the PHP file"* - Regarding Apache, you may want to look into whether or not the server is using [mod_cache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cache.html). Otherwise, I would consider other possibilities such as MySQL, PHP or browser caching. Also, it might be helpful to [edit] your question and clarify what "too much time" is (i.e. does it take a couple refreshes to update or e.g. up to 5 minutes, similar to static pages).